# Border-Spacing and Border-Collapse not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Is it possible someone could tell me why border-collapse and border-spacing are not working on my  elements please?

http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4Bt/177/

**HTML**

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" class="datepicker-element checkin-date__input" />
    <p class="date-output"></p>
</form>

<form action="">
  <input type="text" class="datepicker-element checkout-date__output" />
    <p class="date-output"></p>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font: 12px sans-serif;
}
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 0;
    background: 0;
}
.datepicker-element {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.datepicker-element:focus {
    border: 2px solid #ffd300;
    outline: none;
}
.ui-datepicker {
    border: 2px solid #d6d6d6;
}
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #e9e6e9;
    background: #FFF;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.date-picker-child--highlight .ui-state-default {
    background: #ffd300;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

I am currently using the JQuery UI Datepicker

Kind Regards,

B

Comment: Please specify which code is not working?

Comment: you haven't explained it very well in the question, but I assume you're referring to the table cells in the datepicker popup box?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that the borders in the Datepicker control are on a `<span>` or `<a>` element inside the table cells, not on the table cells themselves.

If the border was on the table cells, then `border-collape`, etc would do exactly what you're trying to do. But because it's on the inner element, collapsing the borders of the cells doesn't make any difference to the borders you see.

You need to clear the border on the inner element, like so:

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {border:none;}
```

And then set it on the table cell:

```
.ui-datepicker td {border:1px solid #e9e6e9;   }
```

There might be more "official" ways of doing it in the Datepicker documentation to cover all possible cases, but that seems to work in the fiddle.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by removing `padding:0` for `.ui-datepicker` `td`. Means your new style will
be

```
.ui-datepicker td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for. Thank you :-)